# how do you return the value of first column of the maximum value of third column?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am working on my numpy HW. For this question, I have to find the maximum weight (3rd column) among the cameras which was released after 1999 (2nd column), and return its productID (1st column).

So, my approach was to get

```
import numpy as np    
data = np.array([[1,2000,143,4546],[2,1999,246,],[3,2008,190,0],[4,2000,100,]])
no_nan = np.nan_to_num(data) # all nan to zeros
new_cameras = no_nan[:, 1]>1999 # get the array of cameras after 1999 (1 column was released day)
heavy = np.nanargmax(new_cameras, axis = 0)
```

and I am stuck here.
I will be awesome if someone can help.

Comment: @Divakar I believe those should be nan... and all length-4 lists but not certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your example and breaking things down into steps:

```
no_nan = np.array([[   1, 2000,  143, 4546],
                   [   2, 1999,  246,    0],
                   [   3, 2008,  190,    0],
                   [   4, 2000,  100,    0]])


# Constrict the array to dates > 1999
filtered = no_nan[no_nan[:, 1]>1999]

# Our productIDs from the filtered array
ids = filtered[:, 0]

# The location of the max
loc = filtered[:, 2].argmax()

# The resulting product id
print(ids[loc])
3
```

Answer (score 2):

<s>Given that</s> If you have variable number of elements per list in that input array, think we need to resort to a loop comprehension -

```
data[np.nanargmax([d[2] if d[1]>1999 else np.nan for d in data])][0]
```

Sample run -

```
In [66]: data = np.array([[1,2000,143,4546],[2,1999,246,],[3,2008,190,0],[4,2000,100,]])

In [67]: data[np.nanargmax([d[2] if d[1]>1999 else np.nan for d in data])][0]
Out[67]: 3
```

Comment: @YunTaeHwang Cheers. Still got the question - You have variable number of elements per list in the input : `data`, right? Like you have 4 for the first list, three for the rest?

Comment: yeah I intentionally put 0s and blanks for nan. data should be 4 numbers per list